# How to pass initial values in Redux form from props(stateless component)?

Tags: reactjs, components, redux-form

My component is this..... I get the initial form values from props in an object and that I need to set it in redux form to further update it.
Point here is also that I have a three step redux form having one form name. [Example is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0Qzz3843)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import validate from './validate'
import renderField from './renderField'

const WizardFormFirstPage = props => {
  const { handleSubmit } = props;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

      <Field
        name="title"
        type="text"
        component={renderField}
        label="Title"
      />
      <Field
        name="subTitle"
        type="text"
        component={renderField}
        label="Sub-Title"
      />
      <Field
        name="price"
        type="number"
        component={renderField}
        label="Price"
      />
      <Field
        name="brandName"
        type="text"
        component={renderField}
        label="Brand Name"
      />

      <div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'wizard',                
  destroyOnUnmount: false,   
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
  validate,
})(WizardFormFirstPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may in the wrong track. Putting value into the store require a connection to the redux but it is usually not recommend to connect a presentational component to the store.

As a consequence, I guess you may like to leave your component as it is and pass all eventhandler from the container to it.

Meanwhile, add a connection to the store for your container component, and push to the store in the callback of the ajax will do.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to access form values from redux-form from different components, you should probably use **getFormValues** selector and specify the form name as params. Pass the form name through props from the parent container to the stateless component. You can then access the form values from the props under the "formValues" field.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  formValues: getFormValues(props.form)(state),
  initialValues: props.initialValues,
});
```